# Reading input volume with CoreAudio OSX

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, volume

The documentation is a bit confusing- can somebody point me to code that will allow me to read the input volume on CoreAudio?  The code I'm working with uses:

```
AudioUnitGetParameter(mMixerUnit, k3DMixerParam_PreAveragePower, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &levels[0]);
AudioUnitGetParameter(mMixerUnit, k3DMixerParam_PrePeakHoldLevel, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &peaks[0]);
```

That works with some devices, but does not work with all devices.  I need something that works for all devices.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to fully diagnose this without a bit more context. However, are you explicitly enabling the input metering on the mixer? You would do that like this:

```C
UInt32 enable = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty(mMixerUnit,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_MeteringMode,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                     0,
                     &enable,
                     sizeof(enable));
```

Comment: I'm taking this code over from somebody else, I apologize for not being clear.  Yes, input metering is enabled.  The problem is that one device (a Tascam US-144MKII) is not giving a useful response- the level always comes back as -120.  I'm looking at whether I can set up an Audio Queue just to monitor the volume- can I do that at the same time as running an AUHAL?

Comment: The mixer should behave device-neutral, I would think. Once the audio is out of the AUHAL unit, it's just a stream of audio data. Perhaps there's issues with the input metering for certain stream formats? You could try querying the AUHAL's output ASBD when using various devices to narrow down the possible culprits. Also, are you *just* looking to get the audio input level? It'll probably be easier to attach an AUHAL to the input and set an input callback (kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback) or use an AudioQueue, as you say.